# MYSQL Workbench. How can I calculate age in sql (mysql workbench)? Then, find the ratio of age in database

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, workbench

Newbie here.

Hello, I was tasked to find the ratio of age in a database. I thought to myself that I probably need to calculate the age before finding out the ratio (I might be wrong).

Basically, I want to be able to find the age of users and the ratio of ages in the database.

The table structure goes as follows

```
id | name | bday | country 
2  | John | 1999-11-07 | Sweden
```

How can I calculate the age and then find the ratio of ages in the database?

Thank you

Comment: What's a ratio of ages?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) -YEAR(bday) 
-- YEAR DIFFERENCE 
- IF(DATE_ADD(bday, INTERVAL (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bday)) YEAR) > CURDATE(), 1, 0)
-- -1 if the birthday hasn't happend yet
AS age FROM users
```

This is how you can find the age

The ratio is a comparison, so you need a base value to do 1:Ratio
anyway please check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_avg.asp in order find the average value (then you can compare it to another one)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you're trying to accomplish this in a single query (age & ratio), but this should compute the age for each individual row:

```
SELECT id, name, country, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bday, CURDATE()) AS age FROM `your_table`
```

to SUM all the row ages together, it'd look something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bday, CURDATE())) AS total_age FROM `your_table`
```

adding in getting the total number of rows

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, bday, CURDATE())) AS total_age, COUNT(id) AS total_users FROM `your_table`
```

those results should give you the total age and number of users needed to compute the ratio!